# Agrupar lista de plantilla

Tags: php, jquery

Necesito organizar un listado para que me organice por mensajes de la siguiente manera:

**nombre1**

- mensaje 1
- mensaje 2
- mensaje 3

**nombre2**

- mensaje 1
- mensaje 2
- mensaje 3

El codigo que tengo es el siguiente:

```
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="templateMultipleInput"><?= __("template"); ?></label>

        <select class="form-control select2 template-input" id="templateMultipleInput" data-target="#messageMultipleInput" style="width: 100%;">
        <option value><?= __("none") ?></option>
           <?php
             foreach ($templates as $template) {
             createOption($template->getName(), $template->getMessage(), false);
              }?>
         </select>
```

¿Cómo podría organizar el arreglo de tal forma que la salida sea ordenada por Nombre sin repetir?

Comment: Te podríamos ayudar más si nos muestras un ejemplo de los datos que tienes en $templates. [ask]

Comment: La salida me muestra lo siguiente
- nombre1
Mensaje1
- Nombre1
Mensaje2
- Nombre1
Mensaje3

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```php
/* Almaceno todos los datos en un array */
$datos = [];
foreach ($templates as $template) {
  $datos[$template->getName()][] = $template->getMessage();
}

/* Recorro el array mostrando todos los valores de cada clave */
foreach ($datos as $key => $dato) {
  echo $key;
  foreach ($dato as $value) {
    echo $value;
  }
}
}
```